# Local variable undefined when it is set in same line

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple echo loop, but it gives undefined local variable error.

```
> puts line while line = gets
NameError: undefined local variable or method `line' for main:Object
```

Why is `line` not visible to `puts`?

I know adding `line = nil` fixes this error. But I want to know why so.

```
> line = nil
> puts line while line = gets #==> Works!
apple banana
apple banana
```

Comment: I dont understand why this question was initially downvoted? I found it quite informative.

Comment: See [Modifier `if` and `unless`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless) (3rd example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You encounter an error, because Ruby parser reads from top to bottom, left to right, so it reads `puts line`, but doesn't know anything about this variable.

Your code will work if you rewrite it like this:

```
while line = gets
  puts line 
end
```

In this way parser will see assignment first and won't complain.

Answer (score 0):

When you give `puts "hello"`, you give information to the interpreter about what to print.

When you give `puts line`, interpreter will look for an object `line`.Otherwise you get the error : `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'line' for main:Object`. That is the power of declaration! Learn to read error messages. All the best!